# R make a column, B, where the value in row n is the sum of A[1:n]

Tags: r

I want to make a column, `B`, where the value in row `n` is the sum of `A[1:n]`

```
A   B
1   1
2   3
3   6
4   10
```

Comment: rawr: awesome, thanks. I was also hoping for a more general solution, in case I have to do this with an arbitrary function one day.

Comment: more general in what way

Comment: rawr: a method where I can choose the function that is applied, instead of being limited to sum, product, max, min. If someone feels like it could also use a more general way of choosing the range of values that is applied for each row.

Comment: There is no 'general solution' that captures unspecified future situations. You may want to read about dplyr package, which offers numerous data munging capabilities with intuitive methods and syntax. All, rollSum() and its family can be helpful if you want last 'n' lags, instead of 1:n() etc.

Comment: That would probably be `sapply`: `sapply(seq_along(A), function(i) sum(A[1:i]))`

Comment: maybe `a <- 1:4; FUN <- sum; sapply(seq_along(a), function(x) FUN(a[1:x]))` then? although note that there are `cummin`, `cummax`, `cumprod` functions which will be miles faster than sapply

Comment: @rawr, and Molx. Thank you kindly.

Comment: @user39 not sure why you call it unspecified. Two people seemed to understand what I meant and provided the same basic solution. Thanks for rollSum().

Comment: The question asked was clearly specified. I may have misinterpreted your general solution or function that is applied and not not limited to sum, product..It is not clear what is being sought.

Comment: Probably the most general answer to this is the [RcppRoll package](https://github.com/kevinushey/RcppRoll) - a package specifically made to speed up this type of function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use the function `cumsum(A)`